# Possible to make TreeView global?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView in Form1. I have a class, called "User", where my intention is to modify the TreeView. Is it possible to make the TreeView global and accessible from my User class?

Comment: That's a very poor design.  Your classes should not be coupled to the UI.

Comment: That's becoming more evident as I go on. I've been trying to shoehorn it together. I'll have to re-evaluate my approach. Thanks.

Comment: Use a delegate from the User class to your Form1 form.

Answer (score 2):

In general, your UI should be a layer on top of all the rest of your "business logic."

For example, you might have some `UserManager` class that exposes a collection `IEnumerable<User>`, from which you populate the tree.  Events on the UI result in calls to the business logic.

When things in the business logic need to update the UI, they should be exposed as [**events**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739.aspx).  Events are essentially smart "callback functions" in .NET. The UI has event handlers registered for those events, and updates itself accordingly, when the business layer indicates changes.

```
class User { }
class UserManager {
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get { ... } }

    public event UserLoggedInEventHandler UserLoggedIn;

}


class UI {
    private UserManager m_usrMgr;

    public UI() {
        m_usrMgr = UserManager.GetSingletonInstance();
        m_usrMgr.UserLoggedIn += UserLoggedInHandler;
    }

    private void AddUserButtonClicked(...) {
        m_userMgr.AddUser(username, ...);
    } 

    private void UserLoggedInHandler(...) {
        MessageBox.Show("User x logged in");
    }
}
```

Using events helps keep your classes decoupled. With a well-designed system, you could use move the whole system over to a different UI, and not have to touch the business logic; only the code that calls it, and listens to events from it.